# NASM refuses to create MessageBox()

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I'm studying nasm and trying to make a messagebox from gcc. My code goes like this:

```
%include "win32n.inc"

extern MessageBoxA
import MessageBoxA user32.dll
extern ExitProcess
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll

section .data USER32

title db "Hello", 0
message db "Hello World",0

section .text
global main

    main:
    push dword MB_OK
    push dword title
    push dword message
    push dword 0
    call [MessageBoxA]

    push dword 0
    call [ExitProcess]
```

I then get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\NASM>cd\nasm

C:\nasm>nasm -fwin32 msgboxnasm.asm
msgboxnasm.asm:1: fatal: unable to open include file `win32n.inc'

C:\nasm>
```

Comment: Check tag for your question. NAS -> NASM

Comment: Read the last 2 posts here http://www.asmcommunity.net/forums/topic/?id=29937

Answer (score 0):

Probably you found this code in that link: https://mathimaaran.angelfire.com/helloworld_tutorial.htm.

You can find how to download de file `win32n.inc` in the link above.

> This file can be downloaded at [http://rs1.szif.hu/~tomcat/win32/win32n.zip](http://rs1.szif.hu/%7Etomcat/win32/win32n.zip)